# In jQuery UI, how to prevent the "pulsate" effect for running millions of times when called consecutively?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-effects

I have the following code (similar to this):

```
$(Auditorium.CometService).on('bid.new', function(event, data){
    $('#feedback').text(data.msg).show('pulsate', {
        speed: 250
    });
});
```

The problem is that for every "bid.new" event, #feedback pulsates X times (default is 5) and sometimes there are 5 bids in 2 seconds, so it queues the animation and pulsates 25 times. I need to forget about the queue of animations. If many 'bid.new' events are fired in a second, should be animated only once (pulsate 5 times only).
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method.

```
$(Auditorium.CometService).on('bid.new', function(event, data){
    $('#feedback').text(data.msg).stop(true).show('pulsate', {
        speed: 250
    });
});
```

*Update:* Added the `true` parameter to the stop() method that makes it remove queued animations for the element (and thus, behave as requested by the question).